# How to log the contents of a ConfigParser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

How can I print the contents of a Python 2.7 `ConfigParser` to `logging`?

The only solution I can find is to write to a temporary file and read that file back in. Another idea I had was to get a fake "file handle" from the logging utility and pass that to the ConfigParser write method, but I don't know how to get such a handle form logging.

Comment: It's really shocking that, even in 2020, the `ConfigParser` has no simple way to get all values for logging purposes.  All answers are very arcane or fail to capture all config (e.g., iterating sections skips `[DEFAULT]`).

Comment: @bsplosion A dictionary comprehension in default Python 2 or 3 syntax is arcane?

Comment: @SeanPianka More that a `ConfigParser` is intended to parse and access configuration values, right?  Yet, as mentioned in my comment you replied to, your answer using dict comprehension over `config.sections()` fails to capture the `[DEFAULT]` section at all - give it a test.  Really not ideal - configuration values should be much more transparent than this.

Comment: I agree -- this behavior is bizarre!

Comment: The `write` method uses a file-like object.  `io.StringIO` is a file-like object.  So, write to the StringIO object and then StringIO.read() will return the string that you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to create a writable object that writes to the log. Something like this (if you want to keep the string around you could modify the ConfigLogger to save it as well):

```
import ConfigParser
import logging

class ConfigLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, log):
        self.__log = log
    def __call__(self, config):
        self.__log.info("Config:")
        config.write(self)
    def write(self, data):
        # stripping the data makes the output nicer and avoids empty lines
        line = data.strip()
        self.__log.info(line)

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section("test")
config.set("test", "a", 1)
# create the logger and pass it to write
logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.INFO)
config_logger = ConfigLogger(logging)
config_logger(config)
```

This yields the following output:

```
INFO:root:Config:
INFO:root:[test]
INFO:root:a = 1
INFO:root:
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So as long as the object passed to ConfigParser.write has a write function of its own, it will call that? Too bad you can't get an INFO log writer object out of the box.

Answer (score 44):

As this is the top Google search result and I was hoping to find a solution to print the values of the `ConfigParser` instance to stdout, here's a one-liner to help all future readers:

```py
print({section: dict(config[section]) for section in config.sections()})
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a python 2 vs 3 thing, but in Python 2.7, I had to use `config.items(section)`. Assuming pprint has been imported:
`pprint.pprint({section: dict(config.items(section)) for section in config.sections()})`

Comment: Note: this does not capture the `[DEFAULT]` section for some unknown reason.  It may be that `ConfigParser` doesn't consider default to be part of its own sections, despite the fact that `[DEFAULT]` must be accessed as a section when getting values.

Comment: An alternative: `config.write(sys.stdout)`

Answer (score 6):

Just use a StringIO object and the configparser's write method.

It looks like the only method for "printing" the contents of a config object is `ConfigParser.write` which takes a file-like object.  `io.StringIO` is a file-like object.  So, write the config to the StringIO object and then read the StringIO object into a string.

```
import logging
import io
import configparser



if __name__ == "__main__":
    ini='''
[GENERAL]
station_id = station_id

[SERIAL PORTS]
serial_ports = 
    com1
    com2
    com3
'''
    cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cp.read_string(ini)
    with io.StringIO() as ss:
        cp.write(ss)
        ss.seek(0) # rewind
        logging.warning(ss.read())
```

**output**:

```
WARNING:root:[GENERAL]
station_id = station_id

[SERIAL PORTS]
serial_ports = 
    com1
    com2
    com3
```

Comment: I needed a way to send `.ini` format over stdin and this did the trick, thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, you can print all sections, including the `DEFAULT` section, by using this variation of Sean Pianka's one-liner:

```py
print({section: dict(config[section]) for section in config})
```

Iterating over config instead of `config.sections()` also returns the `DEFAULT` section.